# Datatable with column filtering but same width as without

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I currently have a datatable with a specific width.

[Here is the example](https://codepen.io/nico-eschner/pen/ZEEXxgr)

Now I wanted to add column filtering like [the official example](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html) but when I add the code to the table, the table gets to big that the width of the area is too small.

What do I need to do to have the text Inputs at the same size as the original header? (So I want exactly a table like in example #1 but with a column filtering row.)

[Example with column filtering code](https://codepen.io/nico-eschner/pen/RwwLjXw)

---

Plain Code from codepen:

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 1370px; font-size:14px;">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Hostname</th>
                  <th>Film</th>
                  <th>AktlHelewafe Version</th>
                  <th>BntlNiJus Version</th>
                  <th>NntjGpuwllre Version</th>
                  <th>AA</th>
                  <th>RR</th>
                  <th>Letzter Keickvcen</th>
                  <th>Letzter Hujlsken</th>
                  <th>Ausstehende Vorgänge</th>
                  <th>Besnakmefojlen</th>
                  <th>Stand</th>
                  <th></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.13.17134.619</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Javascript #1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $("#example").DataTable({
                orderCellsTop: true,
                fixedHeader: true,
                scrollingCollapse: true,
                paging: false,
                searching: false,
                info: false,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                scrollY: "35vh",
                'createdRow': function(row, data, dataIndex){
                    $('td:eq(11)', row).css('min-width', '126px');
                }
            });
} );
```

Javascript #2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example thead' );
    $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" />' );

        $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                table
                    .column(i)
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
    var table = $("#example").DataTable({
                orderCellsTop: true,
                fixedHeader: true,
                scrollingCollapse: true,
                paging: false,
                searching: false,
                info: false,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                scrollY: "35vh",
                'createdRow': function(row, data, dataIndex){
                    $('td:eq(11)', row).css('min-width', '126px');
                }
            });
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just I've added

```
style="width:100%"
```

in the following line of your javascript code

```
'<input style="width:100%" type="text" />'
```

It has worked

Comment: That worked for getting it to the same width +1.
But now the header is not in line with the body anymore. Do you know a solution for this? [codepen of this](https://codepen.io/nico-eschner/pen/RwwLJPg)

Comment: @LastChar23 Could you please  tell me? What do you mean by header??