# Datatable with column filter, header doesnt align with body

Tags: html, css, datatables

Followup question from: [Datatable with column filtering but same width as without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624130/datatable-with-column-filtering-but-same-width-as-without/58624789)

How can I adjust the header column size to the body column size? (not the other way around. The body columns have the perfect width).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example thead' );
    $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" style="width:100%" />' );

        $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                table
                    .column(i)
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
    var table = $("#example").DataTable({
                orderCellsTop: true,
                fixedHeader: true,
                scrollingCollapse: true,
                paging: false,
                searching: false,
                info: false,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                scrollY: "35vh",
                'createdRow': function(row, data, dataIndex){
                    $('td:eq(11)', row).css('min-width', '126px');
                }
            });
} );
```

```css
body{
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
  font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 1370px; font-size:14px;">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Hostname</th>
                  <th>Film</th>
                  <th>AktlHelewafe Version</th>
                  <th>BntlNiJus Version</th>
                  <th>NntjGpuwllre Version</th>
                  <th>AA</th>
                  <th>RR</th>
                  <th>Letzter Keickvcen</th>
                  <th>Letzter Hujlsken</th>
                  <th>Ausstehende Vorgänge</th>
                  <th>Besnakmefojlen</th>
                  <th>Stand</th>
                  <th></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.13.17134.619</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>Systemt</td>
                  <td>4.18.1902.5</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>1.303.522.0</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>X</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td>7 Days</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
                  <td>30.09.2019 15:31:41</td>
                  <td>XX</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

---

Edit: Need to write more to be able to fix the Code snipped...

Comment: For your information SO supports snippets that can be pasted directly into your question rather than using Codepen in future.  This means that visitors can see the running code on this site rather than having to visit codepen

Comment: Okey. But now there are some dependencies missing after your edit. Edit: I fixed it.

Comment: Your snippet shows that the header columns are the same size as the body column, what am I missing?

Comment: @VincentChinner What do you mean? the header columns doesnt align with the Body columns.

Comment: Maybe add a diagram what you want it to look like, not sure what you mean by the alignment.

Comment: @VincentChinner lol. It should look like a normal table. The vertical lines that seperates columns are not straight. [look at this Picture](https://imgur.com/a/swB1LZR). The red lines should be straight, like in a normal table.

Comment: @LastChar23 hehe, no wonder its confusing. you snippet provided: https://imgur.com/IS4KaUL

Comment: Oh, then its a browser problem. It doesnt work on Edge but on Chrome.. The strange thing is, on my real Project it doesnt even work with Chrome but it Looks exactly like in Edge :/

Comment: I cant get it. Codepen works on Chrome and Firefox but my Website only works in Firefox. idk why, I didnt change the table.. The th element even has the same width given from Datatables but ist just wider on Edge and Chrome for me